# Use multiple arguments for SCSS mixin one after another

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm trying to create a SCSS mixin for keyframes like this -

```
@mixin useKeyframes($name, $duration, $direction) {
    -webkit-animation: $name $duration $direction;
    -moz-animation: $name $duration $direction;
    -ms-animation: $name $duration $direction;
}
```

and applying to a div like this :

```
.divs-class-name {
    @include useKeyframes(myAnimationName, 1s, forwards) {
    }
}
```

to get the desired effect of:

```
.divs-class-name {
    -webkit-animation: myAnimationName 1s forwards;
    -moz-animation: myAnimationName 1s forwards;
    -ms-animation: myAnimationName 1s forwards;
}
```

but I get an error in compilation :

```
Mixin "useKeyframes" does not accept a content block.
```

I think I'm concatenating the arguments in mixin the wrong way. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: What version of sass are you using? Try update the package...

Comment: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/75b57038293d7766ab820d866b146b92 It's ok.

Comment: the braces in the end where i `@included` the mixin were the problem. Replacing that with `@include useKeyframes(myAnimationName, 1s, forwards);` worked!

Comment: Not sure why @RenzoCC deleted his answer, it was the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you have to have a `@content` inside your mixin, or just remove the curly braces when you try to `@include your mixin` and it should work.

More details here [About @content in scss](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sasss-content-directive)

Answer (score 0):

The braces in the end where I `@included` the mixin were the problem. Replacing that with `@include useKeyframes(myAnimationName, 1s, forwards);` worked!

Following is the entire code:

```
@mixin useKeyframes($name, $duration, $direction) {
  -webkit-animation: $name $duration $direction;
  -moz-animation: $name $duration $direction;
  -ms-animation: $name $duration $direction;
}

.divs-class-name {
  @include useKeyframes(myAnimationName, 1s, forwards); 
}
```

Thanks @3rdthemagical for this!